# Adding specific column from csv file to new csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to copy few columns from a csv file to a new CSV file. I have written below code to fulfill my requirements. But it is not giving me the expected output. Can someone please help me to get the required results..

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open("C:/Users/...../file.csv","rb"))                
f2= csv.writer(open("C:/Users/.../test123.csv","wb"))

for row in f:

      for column in row:

          f2.writerow((column[1],column[2],column[3],column[7]))

f.close()  
f2.close()
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what do you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second iteration over each row is not necessary. Just access the columns in that row with the column index.

Also, I don't think there's a `close` method in csv reader and writer.

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb"))
f2= csv.writer(open("test123.csv","wb"))

for row in f:
    f2.writerow((row[1],row[2],row[3],row[7]))
```

Comment: thank you so much..it worked..i have 1 more doubt..                                                                            import xlrd                                                                                                                             f2 = xlrd.open_workbook("filePath","rb")

for row in f2:

    print row
wouldn't help me to read the data in xlsx file... can you tell me what would be the changes required?

Comment: @Pkde can you send that as a new question with more explanation of what the error is exactly and how it wouldn't help to read the data. Also, if this post answers your original question, can you mark it as accepted? Thanks